# Testing with `Updated` hook with `vue-test-utils` and `jest`

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have vue component code like below

```
updated: function() {
   // set showPackages = true after all the child component render
   this.$nextTick(function() {
      this.show = this.element.show ? true : false
      this.done = true
   })
}
```

Now, we want to the testing of this updated hook and check that this.show is set or not.

Does anyone have any idea how to write test cases for this lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would extract the logic of your `update` hook to a separate method:

```
  updated() {
    // set showPackages = true after all the child component render
    this.handleUpdate();
  },

  methods: {
    handleUpdate() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.show = this.element.show ? true : false;
        this.done = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

The **unit test**:

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import YourComponent from '@/components/YourComponent';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

describe('YourComponent.vue', () => {

  test('async update lifecycle hook behavior', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        element: {
          show: false
        },
        done: false,
        show: true
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.vm.done).toBe(false);
    wrapper.vm.handleUpdate();
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.done).toBe(true);
      expect(wrapper.vm.show).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

See also:
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html

Additional suggestion:

You can further improve your code by replacing:

`this.show = this.element.show ? true : false;`

by

`this.show = !!this.element.show;`

(see also: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, or at least not entirely, in my opinion. You're testing that the `handleUpdate()` method does what you expect, but you're not testing that `handleUpdate()` is called from the `updated` hook. In other words, you could remove your entire `updated` hook and your test would still pass.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way seems to setProps, has the parent would do

```
it('When parent's index change, call the updateHandler', () => {
   const wrapper = mount(YourComponent, { localVue });
   const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handleUpdate');
   wrapper.setProps({ index : 1 });
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: In my case, this didn't work until I added the `await` keyword like `await wrapper.setProps({ visible: false })`

Answer (score 1):

Updated hook fires when route changes, so what we need to do is to change route.

Add router to test

```
import { shallowMount, config, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);
```

Initiate it and add to wrapper

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "abstract"
});
const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent, {
  localVue,
  router
};
```

And then push new route during test

```
router.push('/route-1');
```

This will trigger `updated` hook